# Bitmap does not work

Tags: java, android, bitmap, android-canvas

I have this code that should move an object down but it stands still can someone say what is wrong??

**First code**

The view class were I display the object code.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class Game extends Activity {
    Play View;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        View = new Play(this);
        setContentView(View);   
    }
}
```

**Secound code**

This is the code were the object should move.

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.view.View;


public class Play extends View  {

    int Y=0;
    Bitmap object;

    public Play(Context context) {
        super(context);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub         object = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.brid);
   }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        canvas.drawColor(Color.GRAY);
        canvas.drawBitmap(object, (canvas.getWidth()/2), Y, null);
        if (Y < canvas.getHeight()){
            Y +=10;
        }else {
            Y = 0;
        }
    }    

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off don't call your `Play` object "View" since that refers to an Android class. Name it something like "playView"...

To answer your question, a `View` doesn't redraw itself when the `onDraw()` completes. To make it do that you should call `invalidate()` at the end of `onDraw()`.

To make the drawing smooth I would recommend putting this into a `Thread` and make a game loop to run the drawing. Look into `SurfaceView` as that is faster than drawing straight to a `Canvas` from a `View`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're expecting to happen, but [View.onDraw()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#onDraw(android.graphics.Canvas)) won't automatically be called multiple times for you, once your view has rendered it won't be called again until something requests a redraw, usually using [View.invalidate()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#invalidate())

You should probably implement what you want done using an [Animation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Animation.html) instead.

Comment: The object is going to go up and down the screen.